# FCM Token Array from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysqli, firebase-cloud-messaging

I hope all of you doing fine ,,
Well, I have PHP page that send CFM token from devises that stored on my SQL Database Server , And I try to send for multi CFM Token devise ,Something like 'registration_ids' not 'to' in order for token devises and I try to use Array($Token),, And here what I try :

```
<?php
        

      define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
      define('DB_USER', 'root');
      define('DB_PASS', '1234@');
      define('DB_NAME', 'token_id');

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
 

  $stmt = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT token FROM token_id where room='7'");
$tokens=mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);
//Itrate token and store it in an array based on your dataset
$allTokens = array();
foreach($tokens as $token){
    $allTokens[] = $token;
}

 // This is a sample KEY
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAWIyTT4Y:APA91bE2Q9WE6MgqIu1-wahFmRK...etc.');

// Build your message as an array
$msg = array( 
            'title'         => "new",
            'body'       => "NEW FCM MESSEG",
            'text'       => "Text",
            'priority'       => "high",
          
);
$fields = array(
'registration_ids'  => $allTokens,  // multiple tokens will be available in array
'data'              => $msg
);
$headers = array(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);
if(!empty($allTokens)){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
}
```

When I run the script Code I got nothing ?!, but when I try to send A single FCM Token that's mean I use 'to'=>data,, like this code bellow :

```
<?php


    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"   { \r\n    \"to\" : \"$token\",\r\n    \"priority\": \"high\",\r\n    \"notification\": {\r\n        \"title\": \"New \",\r\n        \"body\" : \"NEW FCM MESSEG\",\r\n        \"text\": \"Text\"\r\n    }\r\n}\r\n",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: key=AAAAWIyTT4Y:APA91bE2Q9WE6MgqIu1-wahFmRKcKJ4XS2ZjdhwlObeRANTQcrTJlE-2SjZy0eg_mUThWikUDICiZLJOgUtUGUCR4cYuyojCfAB1VJgYqbmHuSuR-S2dn4-UhCfH..etc..."
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

It's work fine and I have resive the messege ,,
Am stuck in this level try to figure out A solution ,, What I mess ?
Very highly thanx to u .